Making a Jira report grouped by Linked Issues
I'l trying to build a Jira report providing the following information:
By Epic/User Stories, give all the linked issues of the type "test".
I already build a query returning all these issues:
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("'Epic Link' in (ABC-1234, ABC-1235, ABC-1236, ABC-1237)")  and type="test"

but I have some trouble getting the right info out of the filter:

This query nor its export to Excel do return the linked issues details (i.e. the User Story/Epic)

...and building a correct report based on that query:

I can't group by linked issues.

How could I achieve this ?
Rem: The ScriptRunner Advanced Search app is activated on our instance.
